# How do I compile bbcp so it looks for local libraries?

Tags: linux

I compiled bbcp but it's failing because libcrypto.so.10 is missing

```
bash-3.2$ ./bbcp
./bbcp: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I check it:

```
bash-3.2$ ldd ./bbcp
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc33fc000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x000000377ca00000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000000377a200000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x000000377aa00000)
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x000000377a600000)
        libcrypto.so.10 => not found
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00000036eda00000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003012200000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x000000377d200000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003779600000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003779200000)
```

Now I get the binary and copy it locally, but `bbcp` still cannot see it.

How do I compile it so it looks for linked libs locally (same dir as bbcp tool)?

Comment: Another option might be to use `patchelf` on the resulting binary

Answer (score 0):

Set  LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to [local lib location](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html):

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib